# is a sample of 2 of 3.4% population too small?

Tags: statistical-significance, sample-size

I'm writing my dissertation and my research wasn't accepted because my sample size didn't meet my Committee Chair's desire for a double digit sample size.  My research involves black and white students in a math class.  There were 20 white students and 2 black.  My research was rejected because of the sheer number of black students.

I agree that typically this is a good assessment in predicting a confidence level, however I'm no statistician and have no idea how to present a justification.  In layman's terms, I'm in Tucson where only 5% of the population is black.  The school has a 59% white population but only 3.4% of the school's student population is black.  In that class it seems to me that there's actually more of the school's black student population represented in this class than there is white student representation.  I have no idea if this actually makes sense statistically or how it could look in running a t-test, it just seems to me that when you have more than 50% of a population represented by a sample that the number's shouldn't defeat the research.

My Chair tells me to go back to Fraenkel and come back with different literature to support a different study.  How can I communicate this to my committee in an acceptable scholarly way that will make sense to seasoned researchers?  My committee is made up of my Dept Head and my course coordinator, so I have to have support for my explanation, but I'm certain I'm right.

Comment: I would say that sample size of 20 is too small as well.

Comment: You have observed two black people: are you surprised reviewers might be sceptical about generalizing from those two people to all black people--or even just to all black people in the school?  The *proportion* of a population in a sample is irrelevant unless that proportion is large.  The *absolute count* of the sample is what matters.

Comment: Whuber, Thanks for your reply.  On sheer numbers I too would see the concern, however the sample was of a total population of 34 black students; getting 20 of them in one class would not be possible.  In fact, of the 34, only 4 took Algebra, 2 freshmen and 2 seniors.  That's why I thought there must be a way to generalize them, because only math was being observed.  Sorry I didn't make that clear.  The 2 observed represented 4 math students of a population of 34 black students in the high school.  Thanks for your reply, kind of you to do so.

Comment: This raises the important question of the objective of your research.  Is it to draw inferences about these four math students, or does it intend to have a wider scope?  Unfortunately, even in the narrowest sense of learning only about these four students, it would be difficult to say much of anything about the two students you haven't observed: the numbers are just too small for statistical approaches to help you.